# "No installation candidate, however the following package replaces it" loop

Tags: apt, package-management, 15.10

I'm on Ubuntu Wily.

`sudo apt-get install libavcodec56` yields:

```
Package libavcodec56 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libavcodec-extra-56
```

That's fine and dandy until trying to install that package:

```
Package libavcodec-extra-56 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libavcodec56
```

Here is my `sources.list`, stripped of whitespace and comments:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
```

Comment: Try this: `apt-cache policy libavcodec*`. Install the latest "candidate" version.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 15.10 we re-introduced [**ffmpeg**](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ffmpeg) [image: Install ffmpeg] as default conversion tool to replace **avconv**. Codecs will be provided by `libavcodec-ffmpeg56`.

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-ffmpeg56
```

The previous package `libavcodec56` is no longer supported.